# Error 500--Internal Server Error with my Weblogic server

Tags: java, json, rest, weblogic

i dont know what does it mean with my REST service.. with my first package (com.rest.employee.model)it work but when im calling my second package (com.rest.my.model) the rest service function doesn't work how can i resolve this..

> Error 500--Internal Server Error
>
> com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException   at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
>     at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)    at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:770)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:765)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:489)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:319)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
>     at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:240)   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:337)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:288)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.initServletInstance(StubSecurityHelper.java:98)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:86)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:74)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.(StubLifecycleHelper.java:60)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.(StubLifecycleHelper.java:34)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.initStubLifecycleHelper(ServletStubImpl.java:652)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:593)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.getServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:403)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:295)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:238)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3363)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3333)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2220)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2146)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2124)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1564)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
>     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)  at
>   weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
>
> here is my web.xml file code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>jposRESTWebService</display-name>

  <description>web.xml for </description>  
    <session-config>    
        <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>    
    </session-config>    
    <mime-mapping>    
        <extension>html</extension>    
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>    
    </mime-mapping>    
    <mime-mapping>    
        <extension>json</extension>    
        <mime-type>application/json</mime-type>    
    </mime-mapping>        
    <mime-mapping>    
        <extension>txt</extension>    
        <mime-type>text/plain</mime-type>    
    </mime-mapping> 

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet-a</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.rest.my.model</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>     
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet-a</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myrest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.rest.employee.model</param-value>
    </init-param>

  </servlet> 

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: How are you accessing each RESTful service?

Comment: im testing it by indicating the address path if it returns an default message.

Comment: A 500 code suggests a problem server side. Have you checked the server (weblogic) logs?

Comment: i see.. i'll check it out.. actually i'm new with web logic and RESTful service.

Comment: The logs may or may not give you extra information on the error. If they don't, debug your application and follow the request thread to see where in the code an exception occurs.

Comment: i cant find the log.. hmm.. but i found it weird when i transferred my model classes to my com.rest.employee.model and the RESTful service is working with that package.. is there anyone could explain that?